# I am trying to add so people can add where the welcome message is sent

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I am using discord.py yo make this bot and i used easy=pil and I am trying to add so people can add where the welcome message is sent but when somebody joins the server it don`t send anything into the welcome channel and I get this error.

the code:

```
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('data/guilds.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        guilds_dict = json.load(f)
    channel_id = guilds_dict[str(member.guild.id)]
    backround = Editor("pic.png")
    profile_image = await load_image_async(str(member.avatar_url))
    profile = Editor(profile_image).resize((150, 150)).circle_image()
    poppins = Font.poppins(size=50, variant="bold")
    poppins_small = Font.poppins(size=20, variant="light")
    random_color = ["black", "white", "blue", "red", "green", "cyan", "brown", "orange", "yellow", "gray", "purple"]

    backround.paste(profile, (325, 90))
    backround.ellipse((325, 90), 150, 150, outline=random.choice(random_color), stroke_width=5)
    backround.text((400 - 2, 260 - 2), f"WELCOME TO {member.guild.name}", font=poppins, color="black", align="center")
    backround.text((400 + 2, 260 - 2), f"WELCOME TO {member.guild.name}", font=poppins, color="black", align="center")
    backround.text((400 - 2, 260 + 2), f"WELCOME TO {member.guild.name}", font=poppins, color="black", align="center")
    backround.text((400 + 2,  260 + 2), f"WELCOME TO {member.guild.name}", font=poppins, color="black", align="center")
    backround.text((400, 260), f"WELCOME TO {member.guild.name}", color="white", font=poppins, align="center")
    backround.text((400 - 1, 325 - 1), f"{member.name}#{member.discriminator}", font=poppins_small, color="black", align="center")
    backround.text((400 + 1, 325 - 1), f"{member.name}#{member.discriminator}", font=poppins_small, color="black", align="center")
    backround.text((400 - 1, 325 + 1), f"{member.name}#{member.discriminator}", font=poppins_small, color="black", align="center")
    backround.text((400 + 1,  325 + 1), f"{member.name}#{member.discriminator}", font=poppins_small, color="black", align="center")
    backround.text((400, 325), f"{member.name}#{member.discriminator}", color="white", font=poppins_small, align="center")


    file = File(fp=backround.image_bytes, filename="pic.png")
    await channel_id.send(f"Hello {member.mention}")
    await channel_id.send(file=file)


@client.command(name='welcome')
async def set_welcome_channel(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    with open('guilds.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        guilds_dict = json.load(f)

    guilds_dict[str(ctx.guild.id)] = str(channel.id)
    with open('guilds.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(guilds_dict, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)

    await ctx.send(f'Sent welcome channel for {ctx.message.guild.name} to {channel.name}')
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nikbik\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\discord\c
lient.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nikbik\Documents\GitHub\discord-bot\main.py", line 40, in on_me
ssage
    print(f"<{st}> <{message.author}> <{message.id}>  {message.content}", file=t
ext_file)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode 
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u200b' in position 
66: character maps to <undefined>
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nikbik\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\discord\c
lient.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 5, in on_member_join
KeyError: '844235494237667340'
```

Comment: Seems like the problem is your file paths. You are saving your guild data on `guilds.json` but fetching data from `data/guilds.json`. Can you try fixing this?

Comment: it worked but there is a new error     Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nikbik\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_member_join() missing 1 required positional argument: 'str'
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001F7BFD9E3B0>
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: That's weird. Can you send the full log? Maybe on pastebin?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Dj3N6id2

Comment: @ItzJustas `AttributeError` is being raised because `channel_id` is of type `str`. You can use [get_channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.Client.get_channel) to get the text channel to send the message to. Beware to pass an int value in `get_channel()` by doing `get_channel(int(channel_id))`